# Saving secrets (API-keys for external application) per user in database (PKI?)

Tags: encryption, cryptography, password-management, databases, asymmetric

I'm developing a web-app which communicates with an external email message application through its HTTP API. My web-app consists of a JS (Svelte) front-end and a Node.js back-end.
Each user on my app will be getting a different API key for each email address they sent from. A single user could, for example, be using 10 email addresses, all (potentially) with different API keys for each address. This is how the external application functions and I can therefore not change the issue of API keys.

I figured that it wouldn't be safe to save these keys in plain text in the database. What if someone broke into the DB? They would have access to most of the data, but without API keys they could not send emails as someone else. In other words, they could not be using the external API and be pretending to send emails as someone else. This could only be achieved by encrypting the keys, I would say.

My first approach to solve this was as follows: use PKI (asymmetric encryption) with a unique key for each user. Each user would get a private key (a password) and a public key. The private key should be the same as their current password (which they use to login to the web-app). The public key can be stored in the user's DB entry. The admin (me) could then use this public key to encrypt an API key and save this in the DB (without the admin having to know their password). Whenever they wanted to send a message, they would be asked to enter their password, which is then used on the back-end to unlock the encrypted API key and send the API requests to the external application (all within the back-end).
In other words, an approach similar to using OpenPGP/GnuPG.

What (other) approaches might be out there for safely adding & storing the API keys (without knowing the users password)?

Thanks in advance!

Please note:
A user can create an email on the front-end which is then processed with custom data in the back-end and thereafter sent by the server to the external app through an API. These requests could not be done by the client (= the browser of the user) due to the amount and total time length of the requests being too large.

Comment: Your question will have opinion based answers. Make it more specific.

Comment: @mentallurg thank you for your feedback, I have changed my question ^